# how do i stop random characters from appearing on android webpages?

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am wondering why these characters appear on certain pages on android devices and how to remove them. at first i thought they were appearing on :before :after selectors because of content:""; on .clearfix and .col- etc in the bootstrap css. but im stumped so i thought id post here. some devices they show up as little boxes with "x" inside and some with "?" inside but only on android devices..

the links below are screenshots taken from browserstack:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7hm00z4bkt8m9i3/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-15%20at%202.17.21%20PM.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qn4a934kos5kdww/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-15%20at%202.17.05%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: The screenshots aren't available, appears error 403 when I open the link.

Comment: you have to allow your dropbox links to be publicly view-able if you want us to be able to see them

Comment: sorry about that

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7hm00z4bkt8m9i3/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-15%20at%202.17.21%20PM.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qn4a934kos5kdww/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-15%20at%202.17.05%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: those links should be fixed now

Comment: Post the html code that is generating these pages, please.

Comment: its too long and i dont have enough rep apparently

Comment: Surely you can point to an url.

Comment: yea i didnt have a live url to give but i do now

http://claimrating.com/topic/donald+trump

Comment: still havent figured this one out